# How to change a call for a WordPress user id to a call for a users display name

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I am working on modifying this plugin in an attempt to make it better fit my needs. However I have been having tremendous amounts of trouble switching from it using the users id to the users display name. I have included the original and my edits below. Any help or recommendations are greatly appreciated!

ORIGINAL CODE:

```
<?php


Class Chatroom {
function __construct() {
    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'activation_hook' ) );
    register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'deactivation_hook' ) );
    add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'register_post_types' ) );
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue_scripts' ) );
    add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'maybe_create_chatroom_log_file' ), 10, 2 );
    add_action( 'wp_head', array( $this, 'define_javascript_variables' ) );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_check_updates', array( $this, 'ajax_check_updates_handler' ) );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_send_message', array( $this, 'ajax_send_message_handler' ) );
    add_filter( 'the_content', array( $this, 'the_content_filter' ) );
}

function activation_hook() {
    $this->register_post_types();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

function deactivation_hook() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

function register_post_types() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Chat Rooms', 'post type general name', 'chatroom' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Chat Room', 'post type singular name', 'chatroom' ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'book', 'chatroom' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Chat Room', 'chatroom' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Chat Room', 'chatroom' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New Chat Room', 'chatroom' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Chat Rooms', 'chatroom' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View Chat Room', 'chatroom' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search Chat Rooms', 'chatroom' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'No Chat Rooms found', 'chatroom' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Chat Rooms found in Trash', 'chatroom' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => __( 'Chat Rooms', 'chatroom' )
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'title' )
    );
    register_post_type( 'chat-room', $args );
}

function enqueue_scripts() {
    global $post;
    if ( $post->post_type != 'chat-room' )
        return;
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'chat-room', plugins_url( 'chat-room.js', __FILE__ ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'chat-room-styles', plugins_url( 'chat-room.css', __FILE__ ) );
}
function maybe_create_chatroom_log_file( $post_id, $post ) {
    if ( empty( $post->post_type ) || $post->post_type != 'chat-room' )
        return;
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $log_filename = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/chatter/' . $post->post_name . '-' . date( 'm-d-y', time() );
    if ( file_exists( $log_filename ) )
        return;
    wp_mkdir_p( $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/chatter/' );
    $handle = fopen( $log_filename, 'w' );

    fwrite( $handle, json_encode( array() ) );

    // TODO create warnings if the user can't create a file, and suggest putting FTP creds in wp-config
}
function define_javascript_variables() {
    global $post;
    if ( empty( $post->post_type ) || $post->post_type != 'chat-room' )
        return; ?>
    <script>
    var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>';
    var chatroom_slug = '<?echo $post->post_name; ?>';
    </script>
    <?php

}
function ajax_check_updates_handler() {
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $log_filename = $this->get_log_filename( sanitize_text_field( $_POST['chatroom_slug'] ) );
    $contents = $this->parse_messages_log_file( $log_filename );
    $messages = json_decode( $contents );
    foreach ( $messages as $key => $message ) {
        if ( $message->id <= $_POST['last_update_id'] )
            unset( $messages[$key] );
    }
    $messages = array_values( $messages );
    echo json_encode( $messages );
    die;
}

/**
 * AJAX server-side handler for sending a message.
 *
 * Stores the message in a recent messages file.
 *
 * Clears out cache of any messages older than 10 seconds.
 */
function ajax_send_message_handler() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $this->save_message( sanitize_text_field( $_POST['chatroom_slug'] ), $current_user->id, $_POST['message'] );
    die;
}

function save_message( $chatroom_slug, $current_user->id, $content ) {
    $user = get_userdata( $current_user->id );

    if ( ! $user_text_color = get_user_meta( $current_user->id, 'user_color', true ) ) {
        // Set random color for each user
        $red = rand( 0, 16 );
        $green = 16 - $red;
        $blue = rand( 0, 16 );
        $user_text_color = '#' . dechex( $red^2 ) . dechex( $green^2 ) . dechex( $blue^2 );
        update_user_meta( $current_user->id, 'user_color', $user_text_color );
    }

    $content = esc_attr( $content );
    // Save the message in recent messages file

    $log_filename = $this->get_log_filename( $chatroom_slug );
    $contents = $this->parse_messages_log_file( $log_filename );
    $messages = json_decode( $contents );
    $last_message_id = 0; // Helps determine the new message's ID
    foreach ( $messages as $key => $message ) {
        if ( time() - $message->time > 10 ) {
            $last_message_id = $message->id;
            unset( $messages[$key] );
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    $messages = array_values( $messages );
    if ( ! empty( $messages ) )
        $last_message_id = end( $messages )->id;
    $new_message_id = $last_message_id + 1;
    $messages[] = array(
        'id' => $new_message_id,
        'time' => time(),
        'sender' => $current_user->id,
        'contents' => $content,
        'html' => '<div class="chat-message-' . $new_message_id . '"><strong style="color: ' . $user_text_color . ';">' . $user->user_login . '</strong>: ' . $content . '</div>',
    );
    $this->write_log_file( $log_filename, json_encode( $messages ) );

    // Save the message in the daily log
    $log_filename = $this->get_log_filename( $chatroom_slug, date( 'm-d-y', time() ) );
    $contents = $this->parse_messages_log_file( $log_filename );
    $messages = json_decode( $contents );
    $messages[] = array(
        'id' => $new_message_id,
        'time' => time(),
        'sender' => $current_user->id,
        'contents' => $content,
        'html' => '<div class="chat-message-' . $new_message_id .'"><strong style="color: ' . $user_text_color . ';">' . $user->user_login . '</strong>: ' . $content . '</div>',
    );
    $this->write_log_file( $log_filename, json_encode( $messages ) );
}
function write_log_file( $log_filename, $content ) {
    $handle = fopen( $log_filename, 'w' );
    fwrite( $handle, $content );
}



function get_log_filename( $chatroom_slug, $date = 'recent' ) {
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $log_filename = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/chatter/' . $chatroom_slug . '-' . $date;
    return $log_filename;
}

function parse_messages_log_file( $log_filename ) {
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $handle = fopen( $log_filename, 'r' );
    $contents = fread( $handle, filesize( $log_filename ) );
    fclose( $handle );
    return $contents;
}

function the_content_filter( $content ) {
    global $post;
    if ( $post->post_type != 'chat-room' )
        return $content;
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )  {
        ?>You need to be logged in to participate in the chatroom.<?php
        return;
    }

    ?>
    <div class="chat-container">
    </div>
    <textarea class="chat-text-entry"></textarea>
    <?php
    return '';
}

}

$chatroom = new Chatroom();
```

EDITS:

```
<?php


Class Chatroom {
function __construct() {
    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'activation_hook' ) );
    register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'deactivation_hook' ) );
    add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'register_post_types' ) );
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue_scripts' ) );
    add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'maybe_create_chatroom_log_file' ), 10, 2 );
    add_action( 'wp_head', array( $this, 'define_javascript_variables' ) );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_check_updates', array( $this, 'ajax_check_updates_handler' ) );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_send_message', array( $this, 'ajax_send_message_handler' ) );
    add_filter( 'the_content', array( $this, 'the_content_filter' ) );
}

function activation_hook() {
    $this->register_post_types();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

function deactivation_hook() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

function register_post_types() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Chat Rooms', 'post type general name', 'chatroom' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Chat Room', 'post type singular name', 'chatroom' ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'book', 'chatroom' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Chat Room', 'chatroom' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Chat Room', 'chatroom' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New Chat Room', 'chatroom' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Chat Rooms', 'chatroom' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View Chat Room', 'chatroom' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search Chat Rooms', 'chatroom' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'No Chat Rooms found', 'chatroom' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Chat Rooms found in Trash', 'chatroom' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => __( 'Chat Rooms', 'chatroom' )
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'title' )
    );
    register_post_type( 'chat-room', $args );
}

function enqueue_scripts() {
    global $post;
    if ( $post->post_type != 'chat-room' )
        return;
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'chat-room', plugins_url( 'chat-room.js', __FILE__ ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'chat-room-styles', plugins_url( 'chat-room.css', __FILE__ ) );
}
function maybe_create_chatroom_log_file( $post_id, $post ) {
    if ( empty( $post->post_type ) || $post->post_type != 'chat-room' )
        return;
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $log_filename = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/chatter/' . $post->post_name . '-' . date( 'm-d-y', time() );
    if ( file_exists( $log_filename ) )
        return;
    wp_mkdir_p( $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/chatter/' );
    $handle = fopen( $log_filename, 'w' );

    fwrite( $handle, json_encode( array() ) );

    // TODO create warnings if the user can't create a file, and suggest putting FTP creds in wp-config
}
function define_javascript_variables() {
    global $post;
    if ( empty( $post->post_type ) || $post->post_type != 'chat-room' )
        return; ?>
    <script>
    var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>';
    var chatroom_slug = '<?echo $post->post_name; ?>';
    </script>
    <?php

}
function ajax_check_updates_handler() {
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $log_filename = $this->get_log_filename( sanitize_text_field( $_POST['chatroom_slug'] ) );
    $contents = $this->parse_messages_log_file( $log_filename );
    $messages = json_decode( $contents );
    foreach ( $messages as $key => $message ) {
        if ( $message->id <= $_POST['last_update_id'] )
            unset( $messages[$key] );
    }
    $messages = array_values( $messages );
    echo json_encode( $messages );
    die;
}

/**
 * AJAX server-side handler for sending a message.
 *
 * Stores the message in a recent messages file.
 *
 * Clears out cache of any messages older than 10 seconds.
 */
function ajax_send_message_handler() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $this->save_message( sanitize_text_field( $_POST['chatroom_slug'] ), $current_user->display_name, $_POST['message'] );
    die;
}

function save_message( $chatroom_slug, $user_id, $content ) {
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );

    if ( ! $user_text_color = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_color', true ) ) {
        // Set random color for each user
        $red = rand( 0, 16 );
        $green = 16 - $red;
        $blue = rand( 0, 16 );
        $user_text_color = '#' . dechex( $red^2 ) . dechex( $green^2 ) . dechex( $blue^2 );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_color', $user_text_color );
    }

    $content = esc_attr( $content );
    // Save the message in recent messages file

    $log_filename = $this->get_log_filename( $chatroom_slug );
    $contents = $this->parse_messages_log_file( $log_filename );
    $messages = json_decode( $contents );
    $last_message_id = 0; // Helps determine the new message's ID
    foreach ( $messages as $key => $message ) {
        if ( time() - $message->time > 10 ) {
            $last_message_id = $message->id;
            unset( $messages[$key] );
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    $messages = array_values( $messages );
    if ( ! empty( $messages ) )
        $last_message_id = end( $messages )->id;
    $new_message_id = $last_message_id + 1;
    $messages[] = array(
        'id' => $new_message_id,
        'time' => time(),
        'sender' => $user_id,
        'contents' => $content,
        'html' => '<div class="chat-message-' . $new_message_id . '"><strong style="color: ' . $user_text_color . ';">' . $user->user_login . '</strong>: ' . $content . '</div>',
    );
    $this->write_log_file( $log_filename, json_encode( $messages ) );

    // Save the message in the daily log
    $log_filename = $this->get_log_filename( $chatroom_slug, date( 'm-d-y', time() ) );
    $contents = $this->parse_messages_log_file( $log_filename );
    $messages = json_decode( $contents );
    $messages[] = array(
        'id' => $new_message_id,
        'time' => time(),
        'sender' => $user_id,
        'contents' => $content,
        'html' => '<div class="chat-message-' . $new_message_id .'"><strong style="color: ' . $user_text_color . ';">' . $user->user_login . '</strong>: ' . $content . '</div>',
    );
    $this->write_log_file( $log_filename, json_encode( $messages ) );
}
function write_log_file( $log_filename, $content ) {
    $handle = fopen( $log_filename, 'w' );
    fwrite( $handle, $content );
}



function get_log_filename( $chatroom_slug, $date = 'recent' ) {
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $log_filename = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/chatter/' . $chatroom_slug . '-' . $date;
    return $log_filename;
}

function parse_messages_log_file( $log_filename ) {
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $handle = fopen( $log_filename, 'r' );
    $contents = fread( $handle, filesize( $log_filename ) );
    fclose( $handle );
    return $contents;
}

function the_content_filter( $content ) {
    global $post;
    if ( $post->post_type != 'chat-room' )
        return $content;
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )  {
        ?>You need to be logged in to participate in the chatroom.<?php
        return;
    }

    ?>
    <div class="chat-container">
    </div>
    <textarea class="chat-text-entry"></textarea>
    <?php
    return '';
}

}

$chatroom = new Chatroom();
```

Comment: Would you please point out what edits you made and why? Taking your code and figuring out what edits you made is too much to ask when you ask for help.

Comment: My apologies! I changed the only instance of "$current_user->id" to "$current_user->display_name"

Comment: Many places you have replaced $current_user->id by $user_id also. I am sure this must be breaking the reference at many places.

Comment: I have only made the changes I noted earlier. Everything else is how the plugin is written. I did attempt to change/modify those values several times and every time it resulted in a 404 or WordPress not fully loading.